# Ruby game of life with Gosu - update action not working

Tags: ruby

**I am creating Game of Life in Ruby using Gosu.** My code is below. Right now, when I run 'ruby gosu.rb' it opens the window with proper dimensions and prepopulated World as it should.

**But as soon as I uncomment '@game.tick!' in gosu file update action, upon running 'ruby gosu.rb' I get the black screen with no prepopulated World wich I cannot close.** Why is that and how to fix this?

[You can find github repo with rest of the code here.](https://github.com/ofcan/game-of-life-ruby) Any help is awesome.

**Here is my game_of_life.rb**

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :world

  def initialize(world=World.new, seeds=[])
    @world = world
    seeds.each do |seed|
      world.cell_board[seed[0]][seed[1]].alive = true
    end
  end

  def tick!
    next_round_live_cells = []
    next_round_dead_cells = []

    world.cells.each do |cell|
      # Rule 1: 
      # Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies
      if cell.alive? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count < 2
        next_round_dead_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 2:
      # Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
      if cell.alive? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count == (2 || 3)
        next_round_live_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 3:
      # Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies
      if cell.alive? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count > 3
        next_round_dead_cells << cell
      end
      # Rule 4:
      # Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell
      if cell.dead? && world.live_neighbours_around_cell(cell).count == 3
        next_round_live_cells << cell
      end
    end

    next_round_live_cells.each do |cell|
      cell.revive!
    end
    next_round_dead_cells.each do |cell|
      cell.die!
    end
  end
end

class World
  attr_accessor :rows, :cols, :cell_board, :cells

  # Scheme of default initialized world matrix
  #------------------------
  #     0     1     2
  # 0 [ dead, dead, dead ]
  # 1 [ dead, alive, dead ]
  # 2 [ dead, dead, dead ]
  #-----------------------

  def initialize(rows=3, cols=3)
    @rows = rows
    @cols = cols
    @cells = []

    @cell_board = Array.new(rows) do |row|
      Array.new(cols) do |col|
        Cell.new(col, row) # note col is 1st, than is row
      end
    end

    cell_board.each do |row|
      row.each do |element|
        if element.is_a?(Cell)
          cells << element
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def live_cells
    cells.select { |cell| cell.alive }
  end

  def dead_cells
    cells.select { |cell| cell.alive == false }
  end

  def live_neighbours_around_cell(cell)
    live_neighbours = []
    live_cells.each do |live_cell|
      # Neighbour to the North
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the North-East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South-East
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y + 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the South-West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x + 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
      # Neighbour to the North-West
      if live_cell.x == cell.x - 1 && live_cell.y == cell.y - 1
        live_neighbours << live_cell
      end
    end
    live_neighbours
  end

  def randomly_populate
    cells.each do |cell|
      cell.alive = [true, false].sample
    end
  end

end

class Cell
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :alive #, :height, :width

  def initialize(x=0, y=0)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @alive = false

    # Gosu
    # @height = height
    # @width = width
  end

  def alive?
    alive
  end

  def dead?
    !alive
  end

  def die!
    @alive = false
  end

  def revive!
    @alive = true # same as > self.alive = true
  end
end
```

**Here is my gosu code**

```
require 'gosu'
require_relative 'gol.rb'

class GameOfLifeWindow < Gosu::Window

  def initialize(height=800, width=600)

    # Basics
    @height = height
    @width = width
    super height, width, false, 500
    self.caption = 'My Game of Life'

    # Colors
    @white = Gosu::Color.new(0xffededed)
    @black = Gosu::Color.new(0xff121212)

    # Game world
    @rows = height/10
    @cols = width/10
    world = World.new(@cols, @rows)
    @game = Game.new(world)
    @row_height = height/@rows
    @col_width = width/@cols
    @game.world.randomly_populate

    @generation = 0
  end

  def update
#    unless @game.world.live_cells.count == 0
#      @game.tick!
      @generation += 1
#    end
  end

  def draw
    @game.world.cells.each do |cell|
      if cell.alive?
        draw_quad(cell.x * @col_width, cell.y * @row_height, @black,
                  cell.x * @col_width + @col_width, cell.y * @row_height, @black,
                  cell.x * @col_width + @col_width, cell.y * @row_height + @row_height, @black,
                  cell.x * @col_width, cell.y * @row_height + @row_height, @black)
      end
    end
  end

  def button_down(id)
    case id
    when Gosu::KbSpace
      @game.world.randomly_populate
    when Gosu::KbEscape
      close
    end
  end

  def draw_background
    draw_quad(0, 0, @white,
              width, 0, @white,
              width, height, @white,
              0, height, @white)
  end

end

window = GameOfLifeWindow.new
window.show
```

Comment: when I run your code from githup, the gol proceeds as I would expect. Maybe post your answer?

Comment: I now know what was wrong. Nothing in the code is wrong, but since I have a weak computer, the game took a lot to load, since it wasn't optimised... I will post the optimisation code here when I do it right.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I know now that the code is correct, it just takes a lot to cycle the `tick!` method through.

**I made video tutorials covering making the Game of Life in Ruby using TDD with Rspec and Gosu gaming library, you can check them out here >** http://svenduplic.com/2013/03/25/conways-game-of-life-in-ruby.html

They contain making of the game from beginning to end, with me explaining each and every line. At the end I explain why the code here takes a long time to complete and optimise it properly.

Comment: shouldn't you select your answer? ;) Thanks - your tutorial vids are great - plugging away with them right now on an HP lappy w/a somewhat adequately powered i3... :)